# RGB components lost while resizing when alpha is zero

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, magick++

I'm using the Magick++ API of ImageMagick in C++ to scale down an RGBA image by half its size.

```
Magick::Image input(input_file);
input.flip();
input.resize(Magick::Geometry(image.px_width, image.px_height));
Magick::Blob blob;
input.write(&blob, "RGBA");
//input.write("out.png"); // Behaves the same
```

### Source image

Original file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoYyH.png

RGBA with alpha as transparency: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuGQm.png

RGB channels only: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RTvC.png

Alpha channel alone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPRLu.png

Notice the three colored dots and the RGB channels where the alpha channel is zero.

### Output image

RGBA with alpha as transparency: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyqiV.png

RGB channels only: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsRuh.png

The alpha channel is correct.

The three dots disappeared. It seems that ImageMagick thought that since the dots are completely transparent, it can discard the information. The problem is, there is valuable information that is lost and breaks the rendering image that expect those data.

I get the same broken behavior when I run the image through the `convert` util:

```
$ convert in.png -resize 512x512 out.png
```

And I was able to fix it with this command:

```
$ convert in.png -channel RGBA -separate -resize 512x512 -combine out.png
```

How can I implement this correct behavior using the Magick++ API?

Comment: Please post the actual original file. When I download from your link, the file has no alpha channel and just shows a checkerboard background.

Comment: @fmw42 I added the original file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoYyH.png

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. I think it needs to be reported as a bug at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=3

Comment: I posted a bug report on this issue.